# How to resolve java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor:TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 Unable to resolve type error?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement

Been trying to call an oracle stored procedure that would take 8 parameters and the 8th is an array that we need to pass. below is the code piece and It's throwing an error. I'm not sure what to pass to createDescriptor method as argument 1 , because whatever I pass it's giving the same error. I've taken the values from Fields inherited part , from the following link  (Any help would be appreciated a lot )https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html

> java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor: Unable to resolve java.sql.SQLException: Fail to construct descriptor:TYPECODE_VARCHAR2

Code:

```
structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("TYPECODE_VARCHAR2", oracleConnection.getMetaData().getConnection()); 
        arrayDescriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TYPECODE_VARCHAR2", oracleConnection.getMetaData().getConnection()); 
        ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, oracleConnection.getMetaData().getConnection(), accountArray); 
        try { 
            //Array array = oracleConnection.createARRAY("OBJECT", new Object[] { "176354516912167301", "177254516082228201" });
            OracleCallableStatement cstmt = (OracleCallableStatement) oracleConnection.prepareCall("{call COPY_FUNCTIONALITY.COPY_ADDRESS(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

            cstmt.setString(1, "ABCD");
            cstmt.setString(2, "PASZKAL");
            cstmt.setString(3, "624954458340565301");
            cstmt.setString(4, "ALL");
            cstmt.setString(5, "RECURRING_ENTERED");
            cstmt.setBoolean(6, false);
            cstmt.setBoolean(7, false);
            cstmt.setArray(8, arr);
            //cstmt.setArray(8, array_to_pass);

            ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you add declaration of method, and definition of array type (collection).

Comment: Please provide the definition of TYPECODE_VARCHAR2. BTW the name doesn't sound right. You would typically choose a name that represents something like "CAR_COLLECTION" in case of an array of cars.